# I am getting zeros as a result of vector additon in cuda and no errors

Tags: c++, cuda

I am running a cuda vec addtion program and getting zeros as the output of its sum later. I have tried debugging but am not able to get to the problem at hand. It should be adding the numbers but is rather simply printing out zeros which I am not able to understand why is happening.

I have tried doing everything to the code and still I am not getting any output.

```
using namespace std;

 __global__ void vecADDKernal(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n){
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if(id<n) C[id] = A[id] + B[id];
}


int main( ){
    int n = 1048576;
    int size = n*sizeof(double);
    double *d_A, *d_B;
    double *d_C;
    double *h_A, *h_B, *h_C;

    h_A = (double*)malloc(size);
    h_B = (double*)malloc(size);
    h_C = (double*)malloc(size);

    cudaMalloc(&d_A, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C, size);


    int i;
    // Initialize vectors on host
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        h_A[i] = 2*i;
        h_B[i] = 3*i;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int blockSize = 256;

    // Number of thread blocks in grid
    int gridSize = ceil(n/blockSize);

    vecADDKernal<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, n);

    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    double sum = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a<n; a++) {
        sum = h_C[a];
        cout<<h_C[a]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"HI "<< sum <<endl;
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was irrelevant with `n=1048576` which is a multiply of `blockSize` (`256`). But as a side note: `ceil(n/blockSize)` should be changed to `ceil((double)n/blockSize)` if you want `ceil` to have an effect where `n` is not a multiple of `blockSize`.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code as is (only adding the necessary includes) and I got non-zero output. Have you verified that your device can run the [nvidia provided sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu) successfully?

The sample is exactly what you are trying to do with vector addition, but with proper error checking and result verification.

A few notes:

- The first line in your for loop assigns (=) a value to sum, instead
  of adding the value to sum (+=), so you will only have the last value
  in sum instead of the accumulated value.
- Proper error checking helps, even with trivial examples. The sample
  provides an example as does the answer Robert linked.
- Did you try opening up the memory debugger to see if your values were
  infact 0 in memory? printing to console is another place things can
  go wrong.
- You can use vectors to store your host data. You can access the raw
  array for  memCpy operations with vector.data() and it gives you easy
  access to all sorts of useful things like range based for as well as
  things like accumulate and fill functions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It is because you run an old GPU with a newer version of Cuda Driver. Have you run the Cuda example provided by Treeman? That example contains debug code. After running that program, the error message I had is

```
Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device
CUDA kernel launch with 196 blocks of 256 threads
Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code no kernel image is available for execution on the device)!
```

That suggests the default compile command `$nvcc program.cu -o program` compiling version is not compatible with your GPU kernel version. To fix this problem, you have to run the following code in your main function to figure out the kernel version your GPU runs on.

```
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
printf("Device Compute Capability: %d.%d\n", deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);
```

Mine shows 5.0. Then when you compile your program, you have to specify the kernel version your GPU runs on, which is `$nvcc -arch=sm_50 -o your_program your_program.cu`  where `-arch=sm_50` is the specification command. Then the program will not produce 0s anymore.

BTW, I run Linux with Nvidia GeForce 940 MX and CUDA-12 on an x64 device. Hope this answer can help.